# How can I work with multiple input lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to output the sum of 1 - 12 lines which contain each two numbers which are seperated by ' '. Because I don't know how many lines will be inputed, I have an endless loop, which will be interupted if the line is empty. But if there is no input anymore, there won't be any empty input and the program is stuck in the input function.

```
while True:
    line = input()
    if line:
        line = line.split(' ')
        print(str(int(line[0]) + int(line[1])))
    else:
        break
```

So after the last outputed sum I want the program to stop. Maybe it is possible with a time limit?

Comment: Timeouts in interactive prompts on the CLI are very uncommon. Are you sure you want this? Generally you wait until the user enters something or aborts (by sending EOF (ctrl+d), sigint (ctrl+c) or entering an empty value).

Comment: It is a practice from hackerearth and there are automated input and I cannot edit the inputs.

Comment: So for example the input is: 1 2 \n 21 5

Comment: Check out my answer and see if it is working for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the case without timeout, and the case allowing you to capture the content (which is usually handy).

The following code has been tested in HACKERRANK. I am sure HackerEarth is the same.

```
contents = []
while True:
    try:
        line = input()
        line = line.split(' ')
        print(str(int(line[0]) + int(line[1])))
    except EOFError:
        break
    contents.append(line)
```

if you don't care about the input.

```
while True:
    try:
        line = input()
        line = line.split(' ')
        print(str(int(line[0]) + int(line[1])))
    except EOFError:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the automated input is coming in via `sys.stdin`. In that case you can just read from the standard input stream directly. Try this:

```
def main():
    import sys

    lines = sys.stdin.read().splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        print(sum(map(int, line.split())))

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

With an input of "1 2\n3 4" to the `sys.stdin` stream, this script prints `3` and `7`.